# Date Format MS Query vs VBA

Tags: ms-access

I've terrible issue with QUERY date format against VBA Date Format.

On Query I've this:

```
... DFirst("date_modification","disciplines_date_modification","[what]='qty_released' and [id]=" & [id_dis]) AS date2...
```

On VBA I need to create a filter:

```
Me.Filter = "[Date2]=#" & D22 & "#"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

When I check date e.g.: 26/03/2021 the filter works, but when I check date e.g.: 03/04/2021 the filter will take #04/03/2021# (mm/dd/yyyy).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In Access you can use mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd. Nothing else is reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes an implicit casting of the date value to a string expression for this.

You need to force a format of the date value:

```
Me.Filter = "[Date2]=#" & Format(D22, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Side note: `DFirst` may not take the first/earliest date. `DMin` will do that.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I tried to force [Date2] with the format.
Thanks also for the side note ;)